# Joining 5 tables with parent child relation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a query with a join of 5 tables, and also there is parent child relation.

I am trying to query university sales and this is my query. I am struggling to get total sales of university. How should I query this?

I attached category table and invoice table.

```
Select invoice.id, invoice.total, categories.type, categories.name 
FROM invoices 
Join sales on sales.invoice_id = invoices.id 
Join course on course.id = sales.course_id 
Join category_subject on category_subject.subject_id = course.subject_id 
Join categories on categories.id = category_subject.category_id
```

categories table with parent-child relationship. [image: here is the structure]

Here is the categories table:

| id | parent_id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | England | country |
| 2 | null | France | country |
| 3 | 16 | A university | university |
| 4 | 17 | B university | university |
| 5 | 16 | C university | university |
| 6 | 17 | D university | university |
| 7 | 1 | E high school | stage |
| 8 | 2 | F high school | stage |
| 9 | 3 | computer engineering | department |
| 10 | 4 | art | department |
| 11 | 5 | chemistry | department |
| 12 | 7 | grade 9 | grade |
| 13 | 7 | grade 10 | grade |
| 14 | 8 | grade 11 | grade |
| 15 | 8 | grade 12 | grade |
| 16 | 1 | England- university | stage |
| 17 | 2 | France-university | stage |
| 18 | 6 | business | department |

and this is invoice table:

| id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 350 |
| 4 | 850 |
| 5 | 65 |
| 6 | 75 |
| 7 | 850 |
| 8 | 650 |
| 9 | 250 |
| 10 | 450 |
| 11 | 300 |
| 12 | 100 |
| 13 | 450 |
| 14 | 950 |
| 15 | 350 |
| 16 | 750 |
| 17 | 320 |

Comment: I fixed the tags and the table @DaleK

Comment: It looks like the column names in the `SELECT` clause are backwards. It's supposed to be `tablename.columnname`, but it looks like you wrote it `columnname.tablename`.

Comment: Also, to really help here we need you to show us an example of what you want the results to look like, and what you got instead (whether different results or error)

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently enough information included the in the question to really answer it, but start with this and tell us what you're still missing:

```
SELECT i.id, i.total, ct.type, ct.name 
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN sales s on s.invoice_id = i.id 
INNER JOIN course c on c.id = s.course_id 
INNER JOIN category_subject cs on cs.subject_id = c.subject_id 
INNER JOIN categories ct on ct.id = cs.category_id
WHERE ct.type = 'University'
```

Additionally, from what I've inferred you want include all invoices for category IDs 3, 4, 5, and 6 -- which are directly Universities -- as well as 9, 10, 11, and 18 -- which are children of the Universities.

This is easy enough to do if you know you only have one level like this. One additional join + a `coalesce()` in the `WHERE` clause can do the job, as could a UNION to a similar query. But if you could have arbitrarily more levels the query becomes much trickier; you must use a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) to check the whole category tree. Also, right now the sample data never shows a University with a parent category. If the actual data allows for this that adds another wrinkle. So again: not enough information in the question to provide a good answer at this time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping out. Actually university parents refers to 'country stages' and then it goes to top of tree which is country. 

for example:

A university --parent_id=16

id=16 -- England universities -- parent_id=1

id=1 -- England